# How to merge n tab separated files by unique first 3 columns and average 4th columns?

Tags: bash

I am stuck finding a simpler way to merge and average n (n<10) tab-separated files, then using `join` on two of them, then `awk` to delete duplicate columns, and then finally ending up with n columns to be averaged. I am happy to do some more "homework" if you can recommend suitable sources to read about. Thanks!

Say I have `N` tables of the format `tableN1`:

```
c1 650 651 3e-07
c2 550 440 2e-04

tableN2

c1 650 651 2.8e-07
c2 550 440 2.1e-04

..

tableNi

c1 650 651 2.9e-07
c2 550 440 2.2e-04
```

The only way I would handle this is using (which can't be the right way):

```
join -j1 tableN1 tableN2 | awk '{ print $1,$2,$3,$4,$7 }' | join - tableN3 | awk '{ print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$8 }' | ...

| awk -v N=$N '{ print $1,$2,$3,($4+$5+...,$N+4)/N}
```

Comment: Only a small improvement: Instead of `awk '{ print $1...$N }'` you can use `cut -f1-N`. In your example it seems like the first column always is the same. Is that so or are there some files with less/different rows than others?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes, all tables have the same number and order of rows (based on the first three columns).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the columns you join on are always the same you can use `paste` instead of `join`. `paste` can join more than two files in one go.

```
paste table1 table2 ... tableN | awk '{ print $1,$2,$3,($4+$8+...+$N*4)/N }'
```

this still requires manual adaption of the `awk` command. You can use a loop in `awk` to work around this issue.

```
paste table1 table2 ... |
awk '{ avg=0; for (i=4; i<=NF; i+=4) avg+=$i; print $1,$2,$3,avg*4/NF }'
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. For the average it would be then: awk -v N=$N '{ avg=0; for (i=4; i<=NF; i+=4) avg+=$i/N; print $1,$2,$3,avg }' Correct? Can you recommend a source to read about awk loop syntax?

Comment: @gdeniz Oops, forgot to divide. Your solution seems ok. However, since all files have 4 columns you don't need the `-v N=...` part. Just use `(NF/4)` instead of `N`, see edit. Unfortunately I cannot recommend any readings. I learned `awk` by looking at examples here on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

A single command using `gnu awk` may work for you:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} FNR == NR{
   a[$1] = 1
   for (i=2; i<=NF; i++)
      s[$1][i] = $i
   next
}
a[$1] {
   for (i=2; i<=NF; i++)
      s[$1][i] += $i
}
END {
   for (i in a) {
      r = i
      for (j=2; j<=NF; j++)
         r = sprintf("%s%s" (j == NF ? "%.2e" : "%d"), r, OFS, s[i][j]/(ARGC-1))
      print r
   }
}' tableN*
```

```
c1  650 651 2.90e-07
c2  550 440 2.05e-04
```